# Update app.config file after installer upgrade

Tags: c#, app-config, upgrade

I'm currently working on a Microsft Word Application-Level Add-in using C#. My application contains an app.config file. In this file I save user-settings (userSettings-Section) and some data defined by a custom ConfigurationSection. The data stored inside of custom ConfigurationSection is also user-specific.

I access the user-settings as follows:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyUserSetting
```

The custom ConfigurationSection I'm using like:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
     .GetSection("MyCustomConfigurationSection")
```

My questions are:

1. Do I even use the app.config the "correct" way? (I know that there is probably not only one correct way, but is "my way" one of these?)
2. Which ConfigurationUserLevel does Propeties.Settings.Default use? Is there a way of setting/changing it?
3. And Most importantly: Is there a way to automatically keep the user-specific settings during an upgrade of my application, but at the same time add newly created settings?

I deploy my Add-in using an installer built with WiX. At the moment I use CustomActions, which manually insert code for each added/removed/changed setting. But I was wondering whether there is a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: I have no experience with Add-ins, but .NET application supports multiple config files. You may find this sample useful [CodePlex: Handle multiple configuration files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5606/Handle-multiple-configuration-files)

Comment: Seems as if you'd have to provide the complete xPath as a string in order to get a value. I'd rather stay with accessing them via properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some researches the whole day now and I think I can answer my questions for myself:

**Q: Which ConfigurationUserLevel does Propeties.Settings.Default use? Is there a way of setting/changing it?**
A: It seems that Propeties.Settings.Default use ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal, what sounds logical as they only contain userSettings... I don't know whether it is possible to change it, but for me it is not necessary.

**Q: Is there a way to automatically keep the user-specific settings during an upgrade of my application, but at the same time add newly created settings?**
A: I found out that there is an Upgrade()-Method in Settings which should take care of copying user settings between an older version of the product and the new one. For more information see http://ngpixel.com/2011/05/05/c-keep-user-settings-between-versions/. I must confess that I haven't had occasion to test it, since I have no permissions to build the installer, but I will rely on it. I will come back to this post after I tested my solution.
Furthermore I am not using a custom ConfigurationSection any more. Instead I derive from System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase, which means that I am able to handle the custom data exactly like the Properties.Settings, including the Upgrade()-Method. See [this post](http://www.juanagui.com/blog/?p=23) for more information about how to use it.

Hope this helps somebody.